# how to make the textview can be slided and display only one line?

Tags: android

I want to make a calculator interface in Android. Now I want to use the textview to show the input formula.
I want it to have the following properties:

1. just show one line whether the content is filled
2. when the content overflows, the excess use '...' instead.
3. the textview can slide in the horizontal direction

```
my xml file
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:text="@string/num0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="80sp" />
```

my activity file

```
tvInput.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

when i add the attribute "android:singleline", the textview show nothing which I had set the  initial content is "0". I had also used the "android:line", "android:maxlines", but if the content exceed, the textview display two or more lines.

Comment: So when you slide, "..." will become text? It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything that would allow scrolling while keeping the ellipsis. The ellipsis only appears when you're out of room, if you can scroll you are never out of room.

A good middle ground would be to use a marquee

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-marquee-text-in-android/

The alternative would be to do a lot of manual labor including tracking user scrolls and appending an ellipsis to the end of the text, until you get to the end of the scroll and then you remove it completely.  The opposite way if you put the ellipsis at the front, which is probably easier.

Views implement this

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnScrollChangeListener

Use it to track the user scroll, and make changes to the text as you see fit.

Comment: emm... I don't want to set automatic swiping, what I mean is that when the content overflows, it stays still and shows the following content first, and you can swipe to see the previous part